# MySQL query not in script keeps firing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that executes a query into MySQL:

```
/*
* Gets total number of rows
*/
$resultscount = executeSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `KeywordTokens New` WHERE `IsItSubjectTerm`=''");
$total = $resultscount->fetch_row();
d($total[0]);
```

…

```
$dbU2Query = "UPDATE `KeywordTokens New` SET `IsItSubjectTerm` = 'YesByF2' ".$regexp2;
    $dbU3Query = "UPDATE `KeywordTokens New` SET `IsItSubjectTerm` = 'NoByF2' ".$regexp3;
    $results2 = executeSQL($dbU2Query);
    $results3 = executeSQL($dbU3Query);
    var_dump($results2);
    d($results2);
    var_dump($results3);
    d($results3);
```

d() is a custom function much like var_dump().

```
function executeSQL ($dbQuery1) {
                        global $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pw, $mysql_db;
            $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pw, $mysql_db);

            //$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','OCLC', '3306', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock');
            //Output any connection error
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
            }

            //MySqli Insert Query
            //$mysqli->query( 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = ' . strlen( $dbQuery1 ) + 1024 );
            d($dbQuery1);
                        $result = $mysqli->query($dbQuery1);
            print $mysqli->error;

            d($result);
            if (!$result) {
                 printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
            echo (DEBUG ? "<><><><><>".strlen($dbQuery1): "");
            return $result;
        }
```

The strange thing is, the output is not what I expected. I enabled logging of the queries in the mysql.general_log, and I found that an unexpected query keeps on firing together with my above code, and it happens all the time.

```
UPDATE `KeywordTokens New` SET `IsItSubjectTerm` = 'NoByF1' WHERE `Keyword` LIKE '%%'
```

No other user and no other script is executing.

What could be the reason this is so?

Comment: `$results3 = executeSQL($dbU3Query);`
You're executing it here.

Comment: No it's not. $dbU3Query = "UPDATE `KeywordTokens New` SET `IsItSubjectTerm` = 'NoByF2' ".$regexp3; has 'NoByF2', but the fired query is 'NoByF1'

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I'll have to have a think but this is pretty weird.